# how to use camel consumer template to consume all files in directory

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-ftp

I need to read all files from the directory and to process each file using consumerTemplate. something like below.

```
consumerTemplate.receiveBody(directory, File.class)
```

Comment: Do this in a while loop and use the method that takes a timeout so when there are no files, you get a timeout and empty/null response and you can break out of the while loop.

Comment: yes..thank you..working fine